# C# .NET VLC AXVLC Plugin - Can't play file from network share

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vlc, smb

In my windows form i can't get the VLC plugin to play files which are located on a network share.

This works:

```
string fileToPlay = "d:\\test.MXF";
vlc.addTarget( "file:///" + fileToPlay , null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo, 0);
vlc.play();
```

Not working:

```
string fileToPlay = this.serverIP + "\\" + this.xdcamCopyTargetDir + this.targetDirectory + @"\Clip\" + item;
```

The Network Path looks like this:

```
192.168.168.19\video\disk-title-2016-05-13\Clip\C0001.MXF
```

The network path is correct. I check it all the time using a textbox. I also tried using backslashes before the ip address. The server is also accessible because i copy those files in an earlier step to the generated network path. If i browse to the network path using Explorer and double click the same file VLC (installed Version) opens the file without any problem.

How can i get the AXVLC Plugin in my Windows Form to play videos from a network address?

Comment: That doesn't look like a network path to me... Prefix your path with a double backslash ( `@"\\"` )?

Comment: http://widtoday.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/accessing-unc-path-via-file-protocol.html

Comment: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=42525

Comment: I already tried \\192.168.168.19\... but it did not work.